# send authenticated request while calling github api to have greater limit

Tags: python, curl, github-api

I was calling github api from my python scripts. if run successfully, it would have made around 3000 calls. However, after 50-60 successful calls, it shows the below message-

```
{'message': "API rate limit exceeded for 108.169.151.47. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)", 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting'}
```

I have read the documentation. I don't have any application to register with to get a client id and client secret. 
From my github account, I generated a token. I'm wondering if I can use that to send authenticated requests.
I tried some curl command to log in through my github profile in the git bash, and then run the python script, but it still shows the same message.

Can you suggest a way how can I make use of the good news in the message?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider just using basic authentication with your GitHub `username` and `password`. The response received should be converted to JSON.

```
req = requests.get(url, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))
req_json = req.json()
```